# Switchmode design for a general-use benchtop power supply?

Tags: power-supply, design

I'd like to build a bench power supply for prototyping and development work. Most of the benchtop power supply designs I have seen are based around a transformer, rectifier and linear regulator (eg 7805/LM317).

However, I like the idea of keeping it efficient, so am interested in building something switchmode instead.

My work is mainly microcontroller-based, but I mess around with audio stuff from time-to-time too. I'm thinking that a 3-rail design (±15V to 0V adjustable, +5V, up to 1A) would cover most things.

Would the increased ripple voltage of a switchmode power supply make it unsuitable for general-purpose use?

Or, given that I'll be relying on this power supply for a lot of future work, should I stick with the simplicity of a linear regulator design?

Comment: Switching supplies don't *necessarily* have worse ripple, but they are *more commonly* worse.  Designing a well-performing switching converter is something pretty specialized, while throwing together a linear supply is relatively easy.  The main thing people are looking for in a benchtop supply is accuracy and low-noise, not efficiency.

Comment: @endolith: I'm happy to spend a bit of time coming up with a decent design if it's feasible; cranking out another linear supply isn't really a challenge anymore. If it's possible to get all three (accurate, low-noise and efficient), I'd like to have a go at it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your output voltages are fixed you should be able to design it with linear regulators with a minimum of voltage drop over the regulators. And 1A is not the end of the world.
A switcher would be more appropriate if you have a variable output voltage. A linear regulator which can supply 30V @ 5A, but which is set to 1V out it will have to dissipate 150W.
An SMPS is dimensioned for a certain input voltage, output voltage and current. If you would vary the output voltage its efficiency will be lower. You won't get the 90% figure manufacturers boast about over you full range, maybe more like 75 to 80%.

**edit**
If you want the +/-15V adjustable I'd go for the SMPS, for the dissipation reason I mentioned. You can attack the ripple with a pi-filter. A high frequency switcher (like 1.5MHz) will allow for a smaller coil.

Comment: It would be nice to have an adjustable output; I'll change the question to reflect this.

Comment: You could make the input to the regulator switchable between different ranges to make it more efficient?  Like a rotary switch selects different ranges of output voltages, and changes the tap on a transformer at the same time?

Comment: @endolith - that's a possibility, and it's being done on certain bench supplies. Switching is done automagically by relays based on the output voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Switchers don't necessarily have worse ripple than linear supplies. If that was the case they wouldn't be used in very demanding applications like supplies for FPGAs and other high-performance systems. If you use a Nat Semi Simple Switcher with their on-line design software I think you can specify the amount of ripple as part of the design process.

I use one of [these](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/4946017.html) bench supplies which incorporates a switcher. Ripple and noise are 100mV p-p.